# Testing function in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I have created a card component and has written test cases for this but on looking into test coverage number I found branch coverage for this component is 50%. And the part which is missing under test cases is testing of else part in onPress function.

> Q1. How can I test this missing part and increase my coverage?

> Q2. How can we test onPress function of Card component individually?

```
const Card = (props) => {

    const onPress = () => {
        if (props.onPress) props.onPress();
    };

    return (<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={[Style.body, { width: props.width, height: props.height }]}>
            <ImageBackground source={{ uri: props.imageUrl }} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>);
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: write a test where `props.onPress` is falsy. If you want to unit test `onPress` move it to the top level and use composition to feed deps into it.

Comment: I didn't get your way. Can you give me sample answer or link to it?

Answer (score 2):

You have two scenarios:

1. props.onPress is defined, so the code under the if is reached.
2. props.onPress is not defined, so the code under the if is not defined.

Props is a variable that you control it, so you can pass the props as you want/need. Just pass the props covering this two scenarios and you are good with the conditions needed.

I don't think you need to test the onPress function isolated. But an alternative would be remove the logic from the component.

```
export const onPress = (props) => () => {
    if (props.onPress) {
        props.onPress()
    }
}

const Card = (props) => {

    return (<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress(props)}>
        <View style={[Style.body, { width: props.width, height: props.height }]}>
            <ImageBackground source={{ uri: props.imageUrl }} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>);
};

export default Card;
```

Now you have the onPress function as exported and you can test as you want.

Comment: Case 1 I have tested. But how to test case 2? If I am not passing anything in onPress then how can I test?

Comment: As I said, just manipulate props to have onPress undefined. Assert if something not happens when is desired so has value as well.

Comment: 1) you don't pass `props.onPress` 2) you simulate click on `TouchableWithoutFeedback` 3) if something crashes your test fails because of uncaught exception

Comment: @CFLS I agree with your approach of decoupling. But I am not sure if this is the best practice of writing test cases